# How can I ListView longClick selector?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector

I want to change background color my custom listview on longclick. This is my selector but only run onClick. What can I do ?

***tables_row_selector.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="#8D2EE4" />

    <item android:state_activated="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/ThemeBlue" />

    <item android:state_activated="true" android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/ThemeBlue" />   

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#0266e9"
                android:endColor="#0484f2"
                android:angle="90" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#bbccff"
                android:endColor="#dce4fd"
                android:angle="90" />                                
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a LongClickListener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) to your table row.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
YourList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){ 
    @Override   
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {
    return true;}});
```

Comment: It isn't running. I set this code in my onCreate method. But doesn't run.